# Error during divide two values on numpy-python

Tags: python, numpy, divide, trigonometry

When I divide sine and inverse sine after converting them to radian or degree.....

```
EA=np.zeros((No_of_lines,3))
 for i in np.arange(float(No_of_lines)):
        reshaped_Matrix=T_M[:,i].reshape((3,3),order='F')
        Net_Matrix= np.dot(reshaped_Matrix, EulerM)
EA[i,2]=np.divide((np.rad2deg(np.arcsin(Net_Matrix[2,1]))),float(np.sin(np.deg2rad(E_A[i,1]))))
```

when I try running this code I got this error message::
'function' object has no attribute ***'__getitem__'***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When asking "why doesn't this code work" you should include a minimal, **complete and verifiable** example, not to mention the full traceback, not just some random snippet from it. As it is now your example is littered with variables that the reader has no idea about. I'd suspect that `E_A` in `float(np.sin(np.deg2rad(E_A[i,1]))))` is a function. You assing the zero array to `EA`, so that seems like a potential "oops" (or any other of the unknown-to-us variables, like `T_M`).

Comment: So sorry is not enough. I am really sorry for this mistake but I thought that I mentioned all the important data. Anyway, you are right the problem is that I was mention E_A then when I edited it to EA forgot editing all of them..

Comment: Thanks a million and so sorry again for this mistake

Comment: No need to be sorry, just that it's nigh impossible to try and debug parts of code that use unknowns and that is why the site policy is to close 'em. They probably provide very little value for future readers. Usually when faced with something like this actually writing out the ["mcve"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might even help finding the issue.